# How can I fix this regex in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to search using this regex in Visual Studio, but it doesn't work.

```
<(script|link)\b(.*?)Site.css(.*?)(script>|/>)
```

After reading [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) I changed it to

```
\<(script|link)\b(.*?)Site.css(.*?)(script\>|/\>)
```

But it still doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look here...it's quite old now but nice to read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/the-visual-studio-ide-and-regular-expressions.html

Following the guide above I tried to translate your regular expression. Unforunately I couldn't find anything suitable for the non-greedy quantifier `*?` and was forced to stick with the greedy one `*`. That's my guess (successfully tested on visual studio 2010):

```
\<{script|link}.+Site.css.*{/\>|script\>}
```

I feel to suggest you a different editor when you want to intensively use regular expressions on Visual Studio resource files like xml stuff. My personal choice was PowerGrep but that's a commercial product. I'm sure there are lots of them for free on the internet.

Comment: you rule!
Thank you for answer and article :)